# Значение выбранного select не передается в форму

Tags: javascript, html

Собственно проблемы лезут один за другим в этом проекте. Вот очередной.
Есть пункт меню Type в нем select. Все отлично выбирается, записывается в title пункта, но не передается в выбранное значение в форму. В чем косяк?

Comment: Вот код: http://jsfiddle.net/martynuk/dbpreadv/

Answer (score 1):

Первое что приходит в голову, отсутствие у элемента input атрибута name.

Comment: там вообще input нет...

Comment: @zorro, там ни input, ни select нет, что должно передаваться при отправке формы? Сделайте невидимы input и его заполняйте наравне с кнопкой.

Comment: что значит ничего нет, все данные передаются кроме Type. Я добавил select в Type, но он не срабатывает. Что такое невидимый input?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="... - невидимый input :) Каким образом у вас форма уходит на сервер?

Comment: эта форма-поиск она перебрасывает на другую страницу по отфильтрованным параметрам

Comment: можете подсказать как объединить кнопку button и сам select, я сейчас сделал как: присвоил значения button селекту и удалил саму кнопку, но  это отличается по стилям. Но выбор елемента передается в форму. http://jsfiddle.net/martynuk/dbpreadv/

Comment: Я бы сделал так. Добавил бы в форму скрытое поле <input type="hidden" id="id_input_for_label" name="input_for_label" value="" />. Потом перед этой строкой кода $target.closest('.btn-group') поставил бы команду на заполнения добавленного поля $('#id_input_for_label').val($target.text()); Только я так и не понял как форма уходит на сервер ;)

Comment: http://bot.immo/ вот сам проект, это форма-фильтр-поиск

Comment: Форма отправляется стандартным способом, так что значение из <input type="hidden" будет уходить на сервер, только имя в name="input_for_label" нужно указать "type", а тот селект, который вы сейчас скрыли, удалить.

Comment: можете это как-то изобразить, а то я уже такого там воротил, что вообще ничего не понятно:)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v5Ljh5bz/

Comment: спасибо огромное работает отлично и значение уходит

Comment: В чем может быть дело, в форму передается вот так значение Type: &type=Appartement%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09

Comment: target срабатывает на элементе списка, $target.text() не вычищает пробелы, попробуйте заменить на var $target = $(event.currentTarget).find('a');